# HTML - javascript count time elapsed from button activation and click on it

Tags: javascript, html, time, counter

I want to create a simple html-javascript page with a text field and a submit button. Submit button has to be enabled every 5 minutes, then you can wrote something in the field and click on submit.clicking on submit, it show how much time is elapsed from activation and submit. Thanks

```html
<html>

<body>
 
 
  <div id="main">
  
  <!-- Form -->
  <form id="form" action="/" method="post">
   
     <label>
     <span>Website:</span>
     <input placeholder="http://" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </label>
   </div>
   
   <div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">invia</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
    }, 2000);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var i=0;
    do
    {
     i++;
    } while document.getElementById('submit').click();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    var time= ( (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = time;
     </script>
     </div>
     <div id="time"></div>
  </form>
  <!-- /Form -->
  
  </div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? Add your source code.

Comment: can you show us your code and where you'r blocking

Comment: Inc mass downvotes. Show us something you've done.

Comment: If a question is solved: Click the tick next to the answer that solved it, don't edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WindowTimers.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) where a function/callback is invoked at every nth time defined.

In your case, button attribute enabled/disabled.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
problem solved.
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div id="main">
<!-- Form -->
 <form id="form" action="/" method="post">
<div> 
  <label>
   <span>Website:</span>
   <input placeholder="http://" type="url" required>
  </label>
</div>
   
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Invia" id="Invia" onclick="stopTimer()" />
      
  <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('Invia').disabled = true;
   setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('Invia').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('tempVar').value = Date.now();
   }, 5000);
   </script>
  
  <script>

  var greeting;
  
  function timeGreeting()
  
  {
  
  greeting = performance.now();
  
  }
  
  timeGreeting();
  
  function stopTimer()
  
  {
  var time = performance.now();
  alert((time - greeting) + "ms");
    
  }  
  </script>
  <input type="button" value="Ricarica Pagina" onClick="document.location.reload(true)">
  
</div>
    </form>
  <!-- /Form -->
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why does it help?